# Приложение вылетает на версиях андроид 6 и меньше

Tags: android

Приложение вылетает (с надпьсью **приложение остановлено**) на версиях андроид 6.0 и ниже. (в build.gradle апи выставлено от 15 до 26)

Вот всё, что горит красным в логе:

```
02-13 16:50:16.182 4774-4774/com.inopei.qwerty E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.inopei.qwerty, PID: 4774
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.inopei.qwerty/com.inopei.qwerty.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
     at com.inopei.qwerty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
     at com.inopei.qwerty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f06006c
     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
     at com.inopei.qwerty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inopei.qwerty"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Как портировать приложение на андроид с апи 15 и выше?

(ньюфаг)

Comment: возможно у вас в xml стоит параметр, который доступен только с андроид6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю , что в imageview вы используете векторную картинку.

Для того, чтобы была совместимость напишите данный код в вашей активности в методе onCreate

AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled

И исправьте в ImageView android:src на app:srcCompact

Comment: То в чём вы мне помогли - навели на ошибку, если убрать этот ImageView - действительно приложение начинает запускаться, но вот теперь вопрос - как сохранить ImageView? Ведь и так было установлено app:srcCompact, а AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled воспринимается как ошибочный код анализатором (не находит решения setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled). Заранее спасибо, если сможете помочь.

Comment: defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

Добавьте это в build gradle

Answer (score 1):

Покажите полностью `build.gradle` - похоже, что есть какая то несовместимая суппорт либа.

А еще лучше прочтите файл `lint-results.html` - он генерируется при сборке и хранится в каталоге `build` - там будут все предупреждения о несовместимости версий

Comment: прикрепил build.gradle. lint.html не нашел, есть только lint-results-release-fatal.html, и он чист.

Comment: смотрите `build/reports/lint-results.html`

Comment: странно, но ничего такого по этому пути нету. есть только  lint-results-release-fatal.html в app/build/reports, и если его открыть, то написано No Issues Found.

Comment: только что в интерфейсе программы определил, что есть ошибка - Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported. Теперь вопрос - как и где исправить?

Comment: Запустите вручную `lint`, меню: analyze->inspect code выберите дерево исходников, сходите попейте чайку и получите результат, потом берите google как исправить `Paint.setShadowLayer()` - самое простое обложить его ифом типа: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW)`

Comment: Так и сделал, исправил один варнинг, связанный с неиспользуемым стрингом. Варнингов нет, а приложение всё равно вылетает...